# Angular shared service returning null to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

I am trying to share data between 2 controllers in AngularJS.  The data is loaded via an ajax call.  This works fine inside the NavCtrl but when calling `CommonBoardService.getSharedData();` from the `DashboardCtrl` it returns null.  I am assuming that it is because the `DashboardCtrl` is making the call before the `CommonBoardService` has set the data via the `fetchBoards` in `NavCtrl`.  I am struggling to come up with a solution to get around this.  Any help would be appreciated.

**CommonBoardService.js**

```
angular.module('EefApp').service('CommonBoardService', ['Restangular', function (Restangular) {
  this.boards = null;

  Restangular.setBaseUrl("/api");
  var baseBoards = Restangular.all("boards");

  this.fetchBoards = function () {
    return baseBoards.getList();
  };

  this.setSharedData = function (boards) {
    this.boards = boards;
  };

  this.getSharedData = function () {
    return this.boards;
  }
}]);
```

**NavCtrl.js**

```
angular.module('EefApp')
  .controller('NavCtrl', ['$scope', 'CommonBoardService', function($scope, CommonBoardService){

    CommonBoardService.fetchBoards().then(function(boards){
      $scope.allBoards = boards;
      CommonBoardService.setSharedData(boards);
    }, function(){
      console.log(res, "Error Has Occured");
    });

  }]);
```

**DashboardCtrl.js**

```
angular.module('EefApp')
  .controller('DashboardCtrl', ['$scope', 'CommonBoardService', function($scope, CommonBoardService){

    $scope.allBoards = CommonBoardService.getSharedData();

  }]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use a notify/subscribe mechanism.  You can create a service that basically has a subscribe function and a notify function. You can then have one controller "subscribe" to an event, e.g. you can call it "sharedDataLoaded", and then you have the other controller "notify" anyone listening that an event has occurred. You use the $emit service to do this.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$emit

Comment: This seems to do the job.  In my controllers I now have the CommonBoardService.getSharedData(); listening for the $emit event on the rootscope.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to share the promise:

```
angular.module('EefApp').service('CommonBoardService', ['Restangular', function (Restangular) {
  this.promise = null;

  Restangular.setBaseUrl("/api");
  var baseBoards = Restangular.all("boards");

  this.fetchBoards = function () {
    return baseBoards.getList();
  };

  this.setPromise = function (promise) {
    this.promise = promise;
  };

  this.getPromise = function () {
    return this.promise;
  }
}]);
```

**NavCtrl.js**

```
angular.module('EefApp')
  .controller('NavCtrl', ['$scope', 'CommonBoardService', function($scope, CommonBoardService){

    if (!CommonBoardService.getPromise()) {
        var promise = CommonBoardService.fetchBoards();
        CommonBoardService.setPromise(promise);
    };

    CommonBoardService.getPromise().then(function(boards){
      $scope.allBoards = boards;
    }, function(){
      console.log(res, "Error Has Occured");
    });

  }]);
```

**DashboardCtrl.js**

```
angular.module('EefApp')
  .controller('DashboardCtrl', ['$scope', 'CommonBoardService', function($scope, CommonBoardService){

    if (!CommonBoardService.getPromise()) {
        var promise = CommonBoardService.fetchBoards();
        CommonBoardService.setPromise(promise);
    };

    CommonBoardService.getPromise().then(function(boards){
      $scope.allBoards = boards;
    }, function(){
      console.log(res, "Error Has Occured");
    });

  }]);
```

Each controller checks to see if the promise has been set. If not, one starts the XHR to fetch the `boards` list and sets the promise. They then use the promise to set their respective $scope variables. Thus it does not matter which controller gets initiated first.